# Different combination of turtles obtaining energy

Tags: netlogo

I have 2 breeds of turtles in my model, hawks and doves. In my model, they randomly pair up and move to a resource patch. Now that they are on the patch, I want them to obtain energy which depends on their pairings. How would I go about doing this?

If 2 doves pair up, they each get half of resource-value (a slider). If a dove and a hawk pair up, the hawk get all the resource-value while the dove gets 0. If 2 hawks pair up, there is a 50-50 chance one hawk gets all the resource-value, while both lose cost-value (another slider).

The first lines of code:

```
    to obtain-resource
     ask turtles with [ partner != nobody and fed? = true ] [
```

Comment: (1) Does it matter which patch they visit? For example, do all patches have the same resource value (as given by slider)? After the patch has been visited, does it still have resources? (2) I suggest you write a pseudocode version of what you want - write each step of your process in English if you don't know the NetLogo. Get your thinking clear and into the question and then we can help with the lines you don't know how to make into NetLogo. So a step might be 'if I'm a hawk and my partner is a dove then I get the resource given by the slider and my partner gets nothing'

Comment: (1) It does not matter what patch they visit, they all have the same value determined by the sliders. The patches will always have resource and never run out

Comment: (2) I know this is not the correct format, but I'm imagining the code looking something like this: 
>    to obtain-resource
>    ask turtles with [ partner != nobody and fed? = true ]
>    if partner is dove + dove
>    set doves energy energy + 0.5 * resource-value
>    if partner is hawk + dove
>    set hawk enegry energy + resource-value
>    if partner is hawk + hawk
>    set one hawk's energy energy + resource-value - cost value
>    set another hawk's energy energy - cost value                                     >    end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not tested but you probably want something like this. At least, this implements your pseudocode. I strongly suggest you don't write anything else until you understand what this code does and how. In particular, you should probably look at the dictionary for `ifelse` and also understand about accessing the properties of other turtles (using `[attribute] of`) and `ask` other turtles to change their attribute values.

This code assumes your turtles are in two breeds - hawks and doves (with attributes such as partner?, energy). It also assumes that there are global variables (sliders or in code) called resource and cost.

```
to obtain-resource
  ask turtles with [ partner != nobody and fed? = true ]
  [ ifelse breed = hawks
    [ ifelse [breed] of partner = hawks
      [ set energy energy + resource / 2 - cost
        ask partner [ set energy energy + resource / 2 - cost ]
      ]
      [ set energy energy + resource ]
    ]
    [ ifelse [breed] of partner = hawks
      [ ask partner [ set energy energy + resource ] ]
      [ set energy energy + resource / 2
        ask partner [ set energy energy + resource / 2 ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```